# Getting data from Modal Controller in IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, controller, modal-dialog

**Hello
for getting data in ionic opened modal in ionic official documentation was written this example**

```
async presentModal() {
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
    component: ModalPage,
    componentProps: {
      'firstName': 'Douglas',
      'lastName': 'Adams',
      'middleInitial': 'N'
    }
  });
  return await modal.present();
}
```

To get the data passed into the componentProps, either set it as an @Input or access it via NavParams on the ModalPage:

```
export class ModalPage {

  // Data passed in by componentProps
  @Input() firstName: string;
  @Input() lastName: string;
  @Input() middleInitial: string;

  constructor(navParams: NavParams) {
    // componentProps can also be accessed at construction time using NavParams
    console.log(navParams.get('firstName'));
  }

}
```

BUT

I also can get data like this —

```
async presentModal() {
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
    component: ModalPage,
    componentProps: {
      firstName: 'Douglas',

    }
  });
  return await modal.present();
}
```

and for getting data in Modal,   for example, the value of - firstName,
      I can do it in ngOnInit    life hook

```
export class ModalPage {

public firstName : string
  constructor( ) {

  }
ngOnInit(){
console.log(this.firstName)  // output will be -  'Douglas'
}
}
```

**So I want to know is this an error? or it is normal behavior for the modal controller???**

Comment: Mate where is the question, here you added the ways and you're saying its both working so where is the problem?

Comment: I want to know is this an error? or it is normal behavior for the modal controller???  because how I understand, the Ionic Modal component is an encapsulated component and we can not get data from other components directly.  but in my example, I  got the "firstName"  value from the parent component  by using  this.firtsName

Comment: I think its not possible and don't know how its working normally so yeah i think there is something wrong.